# How to navigate to different route programmatically in `redux-router5`?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am using `redux-router5` in my app to manage routes. I defined the route as below code:

```
const Root = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
            <RouterProvider router={router}>
                    <MyComponent />
            </RouterProvider>
    </Provider>
);

router.start((err, state) => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('root'));
});
```

below is the code for store middlewares:

```
export default function configureStore(router) {

    // create the middleware for the store
    const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
        router5Middleware(router),
        ReduxPromise,
        ReduxThunk,
    )(createStore);

    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
    router.usePlugin(reduxPlugin(store.dispatch));
    return store;
}
```

In `MyComponent`, I can access a router instance through its property but it doesn't have `navigate` method for me to use. It only has route parameters, name, path, etc. So how can I navigate to a different route inside my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked [into an example](https://github.com/router5/router5/blob/master/packages/examples/apps/react-redux/components/Nav.js)

And it seems that it works like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { actions } from 'redux-router5'

class SimpleComponent extends React.Component {    
  redirectToDashboard = () => this.props.navigateTo('/dashboard');

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.redirectToDashboard}>go to dashboard</button>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { navigateTo: actions.navigateTo })(SimpleComponent);
```

**Original answer:**

I don't know how to navigate with `redux-router5` (at first glance to the documentation it is mainly meant to be used with redux) but to answer your question:

> So how can I navigate to a different route inside my component?

Use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC from 'react-router':

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  redirectToDashboard = () => this.props.history.push('/dashboard');

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return (
      <div onClick={this.redirectToDashboard}>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>
    )
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation)
```

Worth to mention that if component is rendered by [Route component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) then it is already "connected" and doesn't need `withRouter`.